# Can someone explain me how this: $\frac{x+x²}{x²}$... Become this: $\frac{x+1}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried so many times to understand, but I failed...
How this: $\frac{x+x²}{x²}$

Become this: $\frac{x+1}{x}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\frac{x+x^2}{x^2}=\frac{\cancel x(1+x)}{x^{\cancel 2}}=\frac{1+x}x$$

Comment: Thanks you very much, sorry for the bad formulated question

Comment: @Luciano I don't think it is badly formulated. When we perform the division that DonAntonio mentioned, you're secretly dividing by $0$. At least if you want your expression defined at $x=0$. In this case it doesn't matter, because $(x+x^2)/x$ and $(1+x)/x$ are both undefined at $x=0$ and $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+x^2}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}=\frac{1+x}{x}.$$
However, since $x/1$ is defined at $x=0,$ and $x^2/x$ is not, we cannot say, in general, that $$\frac{x^2}{x}=\frac{x}{1}.$$

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the help @Melody

Comment: @Luciano You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Divide top and bottom by $x$.  Same as simplifying $\frac{4}{2}$ to $\frac{2}{1}$.